# Tabularray longtablr: Text from last column text runs out of window

Tags: spacing, longtable, columns, text, tabularray

this time I changed my usage frome longtable to tabularray, cause of the more easy configurations.
First try everything works with my document class, but now there is every longer line running out of the paper by now clearly seen reason.

(I know, the text written in the table is German, but thats not the topic, cause it's not the text creating the issue by what is written.)

I searched here but couldn't find an issue that fit to my problem. I tryed my table in a new document, but the mistake was still given.

Des anyone know an idea for solving this situation? Fist things first: many thanks for reading my issue :)

"Short" example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=alphabetic
]{biblatex}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%   ?
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{graphicx}   
%\usepackage{picins}        
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%%
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{34.5px} 
\setlength{\footskip}{15px}
%
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{svg}

\usepackage{rotating}   
\usepackage{amsfonts}   %   ?
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}


%%
\lhead{}    %left head
\chead{}                        %center head
%%
%\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
%\rfoot{}
%%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0px}    
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0px}

\setlength{\parindent}{0px}     

\usepackage[colorlinks, pdfpagelabels, pdfstartview = FitH, bookmarksopen = true, bookmarksnumbered = true, linkcolor = black, plainpages = false, hypertexnames = false, citecolor = black]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=black}

%\usepackage{tabularx} 
%\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularray} %use X terms in longtable
%\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth} %gives error and all tabularx tables doesn't work from then!

\DefTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{Fortsetzung zu Seite}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}{(Fortsetzung)}
%
%\usepackage{ltablex}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{longtblr}[caption = {},
]{width=\textwidth, colspec={p{4.2cm}|p{2.5cm}|X}}
\textbf{Bezeichnung} & \textbf{Datentyp} & \textbf{Beschreibung}\\
\hline
%
\texttt{Beta}       & \texttt{double} oder \texttt{struct} & siehe bla\\
%
~\texttt{.DataOPT}          & \texttt{struct} & Speicherort der optimalen $ \beta $     je \texttt{tsr} und \texttt{Theta}.\\
%
~\texttt{.Data} & \texttt{struct} & Wird nachträglich nach Optimierungsprozess erstellt.\\
%
~\texttt{.File} & \texttt{string} & Wird seitens der Beta-Optimierung neu belegt.\\
%
\texttt{Reference}  &\texttt{struct}    &Ablage aller Literaturdaten, die der Anwender aus seinen Quellen abgelesen hat. Somit liegen diese an einem zentralen Ort und können separiert nachgeladen werden.\\
\texttt{~.KG19}     &\texttt{struct}    &Daten zu \\
\texttt{~~.tsr}     &\texttt{double} &Ablage des Literatur-TSR-Werte.\\
\texttt{~~.beta}        &\texttt{double} &Abgelesene Beta-Werte aus dem Literatur Diagramm.\\
\texttt{~~.Theta}   &\texttt{double}    &Die zu den Beta-Werten passenden Theta.\\
\texttt{~.Zha14}    &\texttt{struct}    &Daten zu . Aufbau wie \texttt{.KG19} \\
%
\hline
    &   &(private)\\
\hline
%
\texttt{CurrentDateTime}    &double & Speichert das Datum und die Zeit zum Punkt der Lösungsgenerierung für die Ordnerbenennung  ab.\\
%
\texttt{FoldernameOfSolution}   &\texttt{string} &Ordnername der Lösung. \\
\texttt{SolutionFolderName} &\texttt{string} &Default: \textit{Solution}
%
\texttt{DataFolderName} &\texttt{string} &\textit{Daten} = Default. Setzt den Namen des Ordners fest in dem alle Daten zur Ein- und Ausgabe abgelegt werden. \\
%
\texttt{SolutionDirectory} &\texttt{string} &Sollte im Standard-Benutzerfall mit \texttt{IODirectory} gleich sein. Der Programmierer bekommt die Möglichkeit sein \texttt{IODirectory} weiterhin frei zu wählen und kann trotzdem durch Rückdefinitionen im Code auf seinen alten Lösungsordner zurückgreifen. Für den Anwender ist diese Information für den normalen Gebrauch nicht von Interesse. \\
%
\texttt{plots}  & \texttt{struct}   & Bei jedem erzeugten Vergleichs-Plot wird ein \textit{handle} für sämtliche Parameter erstellt. Will man automatisiert Parameter im Nachhinein ändern, so dient diese Ablage als Schnittstelle für den Programmierer um einen Überblick über alle Parameter und ihre Zustände zu bekommen. Für den normalen Anwender ist dies nicht von Relevanz, weshalb explizit darauf geachtet wurde, dass diese Dateiablage in \textit{private} ist. \textit{Handles} existieren in MATLAB sowie Octave. \\
\texttt{~.fig}  & \texttt{struct}   & Figuren-Handles \\
\texttt{~.pl}   & \texttt{struct}   & Plot-Handles \\
\texttt{~.lgd}  & \texttt{struct}   & Legenden-Handles \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image: This is my result in TexMaker]

Maybe anyone can halp me :)

Comment: please shorten your example. It contains code and package that are irrelevant and make debugging more complicated.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you mean shorten my document class or my table? If I would do one of them or both the problem is not exactly described. The columnd text is like flavour text.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Now I deleted codeline configuration out of document class, thats one I know that the issue could not be included. After testing of removing these lines: Error does still exist.

Comment: you are missing a ``\\`` after `Default: \textit{Solution}` and that seems to confuse tabularray a lot.

Comment: Many thanks to you! <3 That was the final point to fix the table :) Many thanks to you and your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (much) shorter example is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray} 

\begin{document}
    
\begin{longtblr}[caption = {},
]{width=\textwidth, colspec={p{4.2cm}|p{2.5cm}|X}}
\texttt{CurrentDateTime}    &double & Speichert das Datum und die Zeit zum Punkt der Lösungsgenerierung für die Ordnerbenennung  ab.\\
\texttt{FoldernameOfSolution}   &\texttt{string} &Ordnername der Lösung. \\
\texttt{SolutionFolderName} &\texttt{string} &Default: \textit{Solution} %\\ missing
\texttt{SolutionDirectory} &\texttt{string} &Sollte im Standard-Benutzerfall mit \texttt{IODirectory} gleich sein. Der Programmierer bekommt die Möglichkeit sein \texttt{IODirectory} weiterhin frei zu wählen und kann trotzdem durch Rückdefinitionen im Code auf seinen alten Lösungsordner zurückgreifen. Für den Anwender ist diese Information für den normalen Gebrauch nicht von Interesse. \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

tabularray seems not to realize correctly that the end of line is missing and then miscalculates the size of the tabular.

[image]

If one adds the missing `\\`  it behaves again

[image]